# Программа падает при вызове SetPixel

Tags: winapi, masm32, masm, gdi

Почему у меня программа вылетает когда я вызываю `SetPixel`? Все параметры вызова вроде бы правильные стоят.

```
     .486          
      .model flat, stdcall     
      option casemap :none      

      include \masm32\include\windows.inc
      include \masm32\include\masm32.inc
      include \masm32\include\gdi32.inc
      include \masm32\include\user32.inc
      include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
      include \masm32\include\Comctl32.inc
      include \masm32\include\comdlg32.inc
      include \masm32\include\shell32.inc
      include \masm32\include\oleaut32.inc
      include \masm32\include\msvcrt.inc
      include \masm32\include\dialogs.inc
      include \masm32\macros\macros.asm
      includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib
      includelib \masm32\lib\gdi32.lib
      includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib
      includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
      includelib \masm32\lib\Comctl32.lib
      includelib \masm32\lib\comdlg32.lib
      includelib \masm32\lib\shell32.lib
      includelib \masm32\lib\oleaut32.lib
      includelib \masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib
     Main   PROTO  

.data?
hIcon           Dd ?
hBrush         Dd ?
hCursor       Dd ?
hImage        Dd ?
hInstance    Dd ?

.data
wc      WNDCLASS <?>
newhwnd dd 0
szTitleName     db 'Window Application',0
msg     MONMSGSTRUCT <?> ; 
szClassName     db 'ASMCLASS32',0
ps    PAINTSTRUCT <?>
rct   RECT <?>


.code
start:

  mov hInstance, FUNC(GetModuleHandle,NULL) 
  mov    hIcon, FUNC(LoadIcon, hInstance, 100)
  mov    hCursor, FUNC(LoadCursor,NULL,IDC_ARROW)
  mov    hBrush, FUNC(GetSysColorBrush, COLOR_APPWORKSPACE)

Mov [wc.style], CS_HREDRAW+CS_VREDRAW+CS_GLOBALCLASS
Mov [wc.lpfnWndProc], offset WndProc 
Mov [wc.cbClsExtra], 0
Mov [wc.cbWndExtra], 0
Mov eax, [hInstance]
Mov [wc.hInstance], eax
Invoke LoadIcon,0,IDI_APPLICATION
Mov [wc.hIcon], eax 
Invoke LoadCursorA,0,IDC_ARROW
Mov [wc.hCursor], eax
Mov [wc.hbrBackground], COLOR_BTNFACE+1
Mov dword ptr [wc.lpszMenuName], 0
Mov dword ptr [wc.lpszClassName], offset szClassName
Invoke RegisterClassA,offset wc

Push 0
Push [hInstance]
Push 0
Push 0
Push 660
Push 778
Push CW_USEDEFAULT
Push CW_USEDEFAULT
Push WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW
Push offset szTitleName
Push offset szClassName
Push 0
Call CreateWindowEx 
mov [newhwnd], eax

invoke ShowWindow,[newhwnd],SW_SHOWNORMAL
invoke UpdateWindow, [newhwnd]


    StartLoop:
      invoke GetMessage,ADDR msg,NULL,0,0  
      cmp eax, 0
      je ExitLoop
      invoke TranslateMessage, ADDR msg
      invoke DispatchMessage,  ADDR msg
      jmp StartLoop
    ExitLoop:
 invoke ExitProcess,eax



WndProc proc uses ebx edi esi, hwnd:DWORD, wmsg:DWORD, wparam:DWORD, lparam:DWORD
LOCAL hDC:HDC
Cmp [wmsg], WM_DESTROY
Je wmdestroy
Cmp [wmsg], WM_PAINT
Je WMPAINT
Cmp [wmsg], WM_KEYDOWN
Je wmkeydown
Invoke DefWindowProcA,[hwnd],[wmsg],[wparam],[lparam]
Jmp finish
wmkeydown:
cmp [wparam], VK_ESCAPE
WMPAINT:
mov hDC, rv(GetDC, [newhwnd])
      push 99806040
      push 380
      push 437
      push hDC
      call SetPixel ;Вот тут всё проблема
je wmdestroy
jmp finish
wmdestroy:
invoke PostQuitMessage, 0
invoke ExitProcess, 0
finish: 
ret
WndProc endp
End start
```

UPD : Ну вот на update вылетает и всё, дальше никак

[image: Экранный снимок OllyDbg с вышеприведённой программой]

Comment: Зачем писать сложно то, что можно написать просто? Этот же код на сях не будет ни значительно больше, ни значительно медленнее.

Comment: @Abyx тему обновил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, вот решение :

```
.data?
  ps PAINTSTRUCT <>

.code
  invoke BeginPaint, hwnd, addr ps
  invoke SetPixel, eax, 15, 20, 65285
  invoke EndPaint, hwnd, addr ps
```